# How to restrict creating default network from docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose

I have overlapping with default docker subnets, so I want to setup for some services custom network. docker-compose version:3

example of docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile


  service2:
      build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile1


  service3:
      build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile2
      networks:
        - net1

networks:
  net1:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.101.0.0/24"
```

So when I execute the following command I got 2 networks :
`docker-compose up --build -d service3`

**project_default** and **project_net1**

But I need default network for other services so I can't change default settings.
What should I do to not create default network if it's not used for the service?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a `networks:` specification for a given service, Docker Compose behaves as though you specified `networks: [default]`.  In your example, `service1` and `service2` are on the `default` network and `service3` is on the `net1` network.

If you really need Docker Compose to not create the `project_default` network then you need to assign every container to some other network.  From experimenting with a minimal `docker-compose.yml` file, explicitly adding `networks: [net1]` to the two services that don't already have it will cause the `default` network to not be created.

If your real issue is just around an IP address conflict, you're allowed to [manually configure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) and this might be easier.

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: .
    # with no networks:, so it gets the default
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.101.0.0/24"
```

Comment: I can't change default settings. It's my local issue that I want to solve. If I change default settings I can create new issues for someone

Comment: Each `docker-compose.yml` file has its own `default` network; it seems pretty unlikely that changing one project's `default` network settings would have any impact on anything else.